# Gaussian elimination from pseudocode

Tags: c

I have tried to convert Pseudocode of Gaussian Elimination - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Pseudocode into actual implementation in C. I have done it, I get no errors, but I am getting the same output as the input. Does anyone knows, where can I have mistake? As a imput I have 3x4 matrix A, where num refers to number of rows (in this case 3) and num+1 refers to number of columns.

```
void GE(){
    int i=1;
    int j=1;
    int k,u;

    while(i<=num && j<=num+1){
      int maxi=i;
      for(k=i+1;k<num;k++){
        if(abs(A[k][j])>abs(A[maxi][j])){
            maxi=k;
        }
      }
      if(A[maxi][j]!=0){
        float p;
        p=A[maxi][j];
        A[maxi][j]=A[i][j];
        A[i][j]=p;
        for(u=i+1;u<num;u++){
            A[u][j]=A[u][j]-A[i][j]*A[u][j];
        }
      }//endif
      j++;
      i++;

    }//endwhile
```

edit:

```
FILE *inputMatrix=fopen("file.in","r");
 fscanf(inputMatrix,"%d",&num);
 for(i=0;i<num;++i){
    for(j=0;j<num+1;++j){
        fscanf(inputMatrix,"%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
 }
 fclose(inputMatrix);
```

file.in:

```
3
2 1 -1 8
-3 -1 2 -11
-2 1 2 -3
```

Comment: You need to show us the variables num, A, etc.

Comment: I assume that you took int acount that in C array indices start from 0, while in "pseudocodes" they usully start from 1. So A should have a dummy row and column.

Comment: Now I am in phase, where I get zero instead 1 in 3rd row... I have corrected it, so I start with i=0 and j=0

Comment: Still no solution :-( I have checked that code multiple times and still I have found nothing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have forgottent to convert tn C this line:
"divide each entry in row i by A[i,j]"
Something like:

```
 for (k = j; k <= num+1; ++k) {
        A[i][k] /= A[i][j];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're swapping the cell `A[maxi][j]` with `A[i][j]` but the algorithm calls for swapping the whole row maxi with i:

```
swap rows i and maxi, but do not change the value of i
Now A[i,j] will contain the old value of A[maxi,j].
```

So you'll need an additional for loop, from [0, num+1) that does that swap:

```
int x
for(x = 0; x < num+1; x++) {
    p=A[maxi][x];
    A[maxi][x]=A[i][x];
    A[i][x]=p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks you are right. But still no change in result, could it be bad implementing of last for?